# Common single page template options

Tags: theme-development, theme-options, hacks, template-redirect

I am developing a common theme for 25 websites, the default requirements are done. Each site has got different single post template. I need to group it as a single theme so i don't need to hard-code every time and maintain a common platform.

The various single posts template are normal-blog / tab structure / List view
 I am now creating an option page for my theme, so that the user can create a layout on his own for the single-page without hardcoding(options might be drag and drop). I need to create certain components like tab,sidebar, list, and save templates for different categories. the values in tabs could be from a custom field,taxonomy. user can create n no of templates for various categories/tags/taxonomy and save it. 
For Eg: Template 1 for category sports,education.

I trying to do it  but i don't have any clue to it, might be the theme atuhalpa came close. how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want users to be able alter the structure of the single.php format without much WordPress know-how (perhaps it's for clients?).

You could create an options page for this, and allow the user to select the structure they prefer.

In your `functions.php` or a plugin, you use a hook to call a function when WordPress loads a page. This function then uses `is_single()` to check that if it is a single page is required, you would then get WordPress to check to see which of the single templates has been selected and then **change** the template being called up (which is by default `single.php` if it exists). Instead it could call up `single-normal.php`, `single-tab.php`, etc (or just `single.php`). You would then create each of these for the various format.

For example:

```
add_filter('template_include', 'template_switch');
function template_switch( $template ){
    if( is_single()) {
    switch (get_option('single-template')){
            case 'tab':
            $template = locate_template( 'single-tab.php');
            break;

            case 'list':
            $template = locate_template( 'single-list.php');
            break;

            case 'normal':
            $template = locate_template( 'single-normal.php');
            break;
        }  
    }
    return $template;
}
```

The `single-normal.php` is perhaps superfluous, you could use `single.php`. Also you would need to add an options page, and register the '`single-template`' option with Wordpress. For details see Codex's [Options Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference) and [creating options pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages).

Obviously you would have to create the files '`single-normal.php`', '`single-tab.php`' etc.

**Edit:** Or, rather than using the switch statement, you could be really clever and (if an option has been selected) simply call up the template: `'single-'.$option.'php'`, where `$option` is the return of the `get_option('single-template')`. This means you can always add more template-styles by creating the appropriate page, and updating the available options and the above code can remain unchanged :D

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you go this route, you **do not** want to name your template files `single-foobar.php`. The [Template Hierarchy interprets `foobar` as a **post-type** in this context](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Single_Post_display). Instead, I would use something outside the Template Hierarchy, such as `content-foobar.php`, and use `get_template_part( 'content', $option )`.

Comment: @chipBennett Thank you for pointing that out. I certainly agree it would be good practise to use a different format to prevent it from potentially clashing with post-type, and the `get_template_part` be a good idea too. That said I'm not sure if the above scenario would cause problems. WordPress will call up a template for the single page (of any post-type), say `single-foobar.php` and then the function above overrides it. So a post type foobar would still use `single-option.php`.

Comment: @Stephen Harris, thanks for the input, my situation is like installing only a single theme with a lot of options, each site has got a lot of components like tab,list,drop down etc. i need to construct a theme as such the user can select the component,structure it(may be a drag and drop) and save the template and mark it for a few categories. With the components in place the user should be able to create as many templates he want.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is slightly unclear, but if I'm following you correctly: you need one Theme, that has several templates for `single.php`?

If that's the case, I would recommend creating the base Theme, and then using **Child Themes** to customize `single.php`. Doing so is the simplest way to override a single template file several times, and minimizes code repetition.

Comment: sir, thanks for the input, my situation is like installing only a single theme with a lot of options, each site has got a lot of components like tab,list,drop down etc. i need to construct a theme as such the user can select the component,structure it(may be a drag and drop) and save the template and mark it for a few categories. With the components in place the user should be able to create as many templates user wants.